# How to require a type can be an argument of a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I need a `typename T` only that can be an argument of `std::wfstream::operator<<`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
requires // Something here. I tested "std::invoke<std::wfstream::operator<<, K>"
void foo(T t) {
    std::wfstream file{};
    file << k;
}

void main() {
    std::string str;
    std::wstring wstr;

    std::wfstream file{};

    file << str; // editor warns no operator << matches
    file << wstr;
    file << "s";
    file << L"s";

    foo(str); // error while compile-time
    foo(wstr);
    foo("s");
    foo(L"s");
}
```

I looked up `std::invocable` and `std::invoke`, but it was for an object has `operator()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `requires`-clause to constrain that `file << t` must be a valid expression

```
#include <fstream>

template<typename T>
concept wfstream_insertable = 
    requires(std::wfstream& f, T& t) { f << t; };

template<wfstream_insertable T> 
void foo(T t) {
    std::wfstream file{};
    file << t;
};
```